# Could not connect to development server react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run my app on an ios simulator, however, when I run it, it says cannot connect to development server. An image of the simulator is below. I've looked at the answers for similar problems, however, they don't work. For example, I tried restarting the ios simulator, running npm start again, etc.

What I suspect is happening is the ios simulator is trying to connect to port 19001, however, my developer tab that opens when I run npm start is trying to run on port 19000. However, I might be wrong.

If anyone knows anything that might solve this, I would be very grateful. Thank you!

[ios simulator picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLYgo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likely due the incorrect ports. If you cannot change the simulator port you can try start the npm at 19001:

```
react-native start --port=19001
```

Comment: Which file do I put this in?

Comment: You run on your terminal/console.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of these:

1. Reset your simulator
2. Remove and install node modules
3. Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
4. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache.
5. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*